# How do I find/use op:except with the multiple xml files?

Tags: xquery

How do I find/use op:except with the multiple xml files?

I've gotten the nodes from file 1 and file 2, and in the xquery expression I'm tring to find the op:except of those two. When I use op:except, I end up getting an empty set.

XML File 1:

```
<a>txt</a>
<a>txt2</a>
<a>txt3</a>
```

XML File 2:

```
<a>txt2</a>
<a>txt4</a>
<a>txt3</a>
```

I want output from op:($nodesfromfile1, $nodesfromfile2) to be:

```
<a>txt</a>
```

Comment: Odd. You say that using 'except' returns an empty set. Except is based on node identity. The node identities are different here (since the nodes come from different files), so the result should be the left operand..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It effectively comes down to the single line behind the return in the following code. You could put that in a function if you like, but it is already very dense, so maybe not worth it..

```
let $file1 := (
    <a>txt</a>,
    <a>txt2</a>,
    <a>txt3</a>
)
let $file2 := (
    <a>txt2</a>,
    <a>txt4</a>,
    <a>txt3</a>
)
return
    $file1[not(. = $file2)]
```

Note, you also have the 'except' keyword (`$file1 except $file2`), but that works on node *identity* which won't work if the nodes comes from different files.

By the way, above code uses string-equality for comparison. If you would prefer to do a comparison on full node-structure, you could also use the `deep-equal()` function.

HTH!